# Ciclo While reescribe variable de control

Tags: python, while

Estoy haciendo un programa que lance dados al azar y pregunte al usuario si quiere volver a lanzarlos, hasta ahí todo bien, tengo que usar un ciclo while para relanzar los dados si es el caso.

Este es mi código:

```py
import random

def lanzaDados():
    a = randomizarDado()
    b = randomizarDado()
    print("El dado1 es:", a)
    print("El dado2 es:", b)
    print("La suma de los dados es: ", a+b)
    c= input("Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: ")
    while(c == 's'):
        lanzaDados()
        
def randomizarDado():
    return int((random.random()*10)%6+1)

lanzaDados()
```

El asunto es que si la primera vez que se pregunta al usuario se selecciona que sí se desea relanzar los dados, todas las demás veces el ciclo sobreescribe la variable de control del ciclo while por la opción "s" (La que se selecciona en un para continuar el ciclo la primera vez) a pesar de ingresar algo distinto en el input.

He hecho debug y la sobreescritura sucede exactamente cuando se evalúa la condición del ciclo while, en ese momento el valor de la variable "c" cambia de "n" a "s" por alguna razón. Espero me puedan iluminar un poco en este asunto. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué terminal o shell estás usando? Sospecho que es un problema de tu sistema operativo y no de python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entendi bien cual es tu problema, incluso después de ejecutar tu código. El resultado concuerda con lo que tienes escrito. No hay nada que se este sobreescribiendo, aunque lo parezca.

Estás haciendo llamadas *recursivas* a `lanzaDados`, técnica que probablemente no hayas visto aún. En todo caso, la recursión no es necesaria en el ejemplo y no es la condición requerida para el ejercicio por lo que entiendo.

Puedes evitar la recursión reescribiendo el código con `while` de la siguiente manera:

```
import random

def randomizarDado():
    return random.randint(1,6)

def lanzaDados():
    while True:
        a = randomizarDado()
        b = randomizarDado()
        print(f"El dado1 es {a}")
        print(f"El dado1 es {b}")
        print(f"La suma de los dados es: {a + b}")

        c = input("Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: ")
        if c == "s":
            break

lanzaDados()
```

Nota: Una función recursiva es aquella que se llama a si misma. En cada llamada se genera un nuevo juego de variables en el stack, con lo que el stack crece y crece. Si no controlas bien la ejecución, puedes terminar comiendote toda la RAM.

Puede ser díficil de visualizar, pues tienes un mismo código que está corriendo varias veces al mismo tiempo.

Tal vez te ayude asi: piensa que existen múltiples copias: lanzaDados0, lanzaDados1, lanzaDados2, ...

Cada vez que invocas a lanzaDados dentro de si mismo, es como si llamaras a la siguiente copia:

```
lanzaDados0() -> lanzaDados1() -> lanzaDados2() -> ...
```

Mismo código, distintas instancias. Cada instancia tiene su propio juego de variables locales.

Si no entiendes, no importa. Es algo que se le escape incluso a profesionales. Ya lo verás más adelante.

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario involucrar el ciclo `while` aquí, es mejor evaluar la entrada del usuario con `if`. Dependiendo de esta validación se aplica la recursividad de la función.

```
c = input("Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: ")
if c == "s":
    lanzaDados()
```

**Otras observaciones a tu código:**

Si quieres retornar un valor aleatorio entre números enteros, existe la función `randint()`. Esta usa como argumentos el rango donde se quiere buscar un número aleatorio. Esto es más fácil y entendible que lo que estabas haciendo.

```
def randomizarDado():
    return random.randint(1,6)
```

Te recomiedno la concatenación con la notación `f"{}"` es más entendible.

```
print(f"El dado1 es {a}")
print(f"El dado1 es {b}")
print(f"La suma de los dados es: {a + b}")
```

También es buena idea definir la funciones antes de invocarlas, más que todo por orden y para prevenir errores.

**Solución:**

Dicho lo anterior mi propuesta de solución es la siguiente:

```
import random

def randomizarDado():
    return random.randint(1,6)

def lanzaDados():
    a = randomizarDado()
    b = randomizarDado()
    print(f"El dado1 es {a}")
    print(f"El dado1 es {b}")
    print(f"La suma de los dados es: {a + b}")

    c = input("Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: ")
    if c == "s":
        lanzaDados()

lanzaDados()
```

**Resultados:**

Te adjunto una ejecución para que veas el resultado final:

```
El dado1 es 4
El dado1 es 3
La suma de los dados es: 7
Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: s
El dado1 es 5
El dado1 es 3
La suma de los dados es: 8
Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: s
El dado1 es 3
El dado1 es 3
La suma de los dados es: 6
Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: s
El dado1 es 6
El dado1 es 5
La suma de los dados es: 11
Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: s
El dado1 es 2
El dado1 es 5
La suma de los dados es: 7
Desea volver a tirar los dados? s/n: n
```

Espero que te haya servido, salu3 xD!

Comment: Estoy absolutamente de acuerdo en que es más práctico usar un if. Esto es un ejercicio para un curso, en principio usé el ciclo if, pero en la rubrica (Y sin previo aviso) dijeron que es necesario usar el ciclo while. Gracias también por los consejos, me parecen muy acertados. Sin embargo, la duda del por qué se está reescribiendo la  variable sigue